# Ogg (sound) web player

Tags: java, html, ogg

In our company, we have thousands of ogg sound files and I am writing html app in which I want to play them. I know mp3 flash based web players, but I can not convert anything. I need somewhat, which runs on Firefox, Chrome, IE9+ - IE is a problem. I found jorbis project, but when I dowloaded it, I can not run it (classnotfoundexeption). I know, ogg on web is problem. Thanks for answers.

Comment: Look at the Ogg site: http://www.vorbis.com/setup_windows/. It lists lots of options.  Alternatively, if you give us a better description of how you are trying to use 'jorbis' and what happens, maybe we could help with that./

Comment: You might look into using CherryMusic. I don't have any personal experience with it, but it looks like it supports live transcoding of ogg files. See http://www.fomori.org/cherrymusic/

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I founded soulution - I use audio tag in modern browsers with fallback in IE, which does not play it. In IE I use cortado.jar now and it works ok on our computers.